# Using keywords vs real phrases for translation

Tags: python, django, internationalization, translation, templating

For a website with a large amount of fixed strings (labels, announcements and etc), I'm going to add internationalization to the project and I want to know your experiences about using keywords vs real phrases in the original codes? Which one is better to use?

Check this example - in django:

Real phrase:

```
<p>
    {% trans "Welcome to my website" %}
</p>
```

Keyword:

```
<p>
    {% trans "WELCOME_MESSAGE" %}
</p>
```

Of course using real phrases is easier, but I have some bad experiences. Consider a general word, `{% trans "contacts" %}` used as title of a page and somewhere else used in a phrase like `{{selected_contacts_count}}{% trans "contacts" %}`, translation of `contacts` as title of a page can be different with translation of `contacts` as a word in a phrase, so this is a conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keywords.

Somewhere , sometime, someplace, you'll need to have a translation table.  It might be flat file, it might be a db store, but it'll probably look like this:

```
field | language | message
```

it'll be much easier to build and maintain a keyword based system :

```
WELCOME_MESSAGE | EN | Welcome to our online h ome
WELCOME_MESSAGE | FR | bienvenue chez nous en ligne
WELCOME_MESSAGE | SW | kuwakaribisha nyumbani kwetu online
```

If you're interpolating data into these translation, the one issue that you'll likely encounter is having to deal with pluralizations:

```
There is one item.  
There are four items.

You have one new message.
You have four new messages.
```

So keep that in mind as you move forward.

Answer (score 2):

Of course that keywords are better, not only because they are easier to read for a programmer, but also makes finding those strings in files faster, and you are not 'tied' to one language (e.g. English)

Answer (score 2):

This is i think mostly a question of personal taste.

Using real phrases you will meet the mentioned collisions, for your example you may use

`{% blocktrans %}{{selected_contacts_count}} contacts{% endblocktrans %}` instead.

Using keywords you have to create a unique keyword for all translations which may not be so easy when your project grows, so it might be a good idea to devise some kind of naming convention beforehand.